# What to call words with permanent prefix, but no unprefixed form? (ex: nonchalant, untoward)

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

What do you call prefixed words with no unprefixed counterpart? For example, there's no such thing as a "chalant person". Bad behavior may be "untoward", good behavior is never "toward". What are these words called and why do they exist? Did unprefixed versions ever exist?

Comment: http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/humor/how-i-met-my-wife.html

Comment: I like "gruntled" personally

Comment: "I dreamt of a corrigible nocuous youth, Gainly, gruntled and kempt; A mayed and sidious fellow forsooth; Ordinate, effable, shevelled, ept, couth; A delible fellow I dreamt." (*A Dream of Couth*, from *A Game of Words*)

Comment: [I have no idea, but I know who might...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IngvNUaWvck)

Comment: **THIS IS A FANTASTIC QUESTION**

Comment: It is utterly hilarious, and so typical of this site, that the question has attracted close votes.

Answer (score 2):

Edwin Ashworth's comment (which is beneath your question) sent me to the linked question, the answer to which in turn sent me to the following site:  http://www.2wheels.org.uk/return/absent-antonyms.asp. "2wheels" published there his work in progress regarding ***missing antonyms***, which is the term I believe you are looking for. The list (a work in progress) of missing antonyms suggested by "2wheels" and the comment which precedes it are as follows:

> "In no particular order, my list looks like this at the moment, and those with asterisks qualify as perfect absent antonyms, where the presumed positive is, so far as I know, never found. Those without asterisks have positive forms that are occasionally found, but very much more rarely than the negative form:
>
> - **"Unrequited** (requited is very rarely used).
> - **Unfathomable** (used very much more than fathomable, which, when used, is usually in a negative construction such as scarcely fathomable).
> - **Inordinate** (much more common than ordinate).
> - **Untrammelled** (trammelled is rarely found).
> - Untoward (though toward is a common word, untoward still qualifies under rule six).
> - ***Intact** (Tact is a commonly-found word, if not a commonly found quality, but its usual meaning (conveying the sense of polite discretion) is unrelated to intact, so the word qualifies under rule six. Intact, meaning untouched or undamaged, has a presumed positive form tact, meaning damaged, but one rarely hears American soldiers saying: "We blew that city up pretty well - man, it was totally tact."
> - ***Infinity** (finite, the adjective, is common enough, but I have never seen the presumed abstract noun finity, which ought, were it to exist, to convey the concept of boundedness).
> - ***Inept** (the adjective ept is absent).
> - ***Nonsensical** (sensical is not found).
> - **Unmissable** (missable is not recognised by my computer, though it is now perhaps becoming unofficially common when used as a sarcastic comment on, for example, a tedious museum).
> - **Insufferable** (sufferable seems much rarer).
> - **Uncouth** (couth is found, but much less often than its negative counterpart).
> - ***Unspeakable** (speakable is not found).
> - **Unstinting** (stinting is very rarely found).
> - **Unthinkable** (thinkable is very rarely found, and then usually in a negative construction such as barely thinkable).
> - ***Insomnia** (somnia is not found).
> - **Unperturbed** (found more often than the odd-looking perturbed).
> - ***Indescribably** (describably does not make it onto my computer's spell-checker; it might just scrape its way into a large dictionary, one of which to hand I do not have).
> - ***Ruthless** (qualifies as a wild-card under rule 9, having no apparent connection with Ruth.)
> - **Ineffable** (effable is rarely seen or heard)"

Comment: I'm not so sure about "nonsensical". I know I've used ["sensical"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105988/does-the-interval-notation-a-b-imply-that-ab/1106038#1106038) without batting an eyebrow and I've certainly seen it used elsewhere - it's certainly not the same level of nonsense as "finity"

Comment: Regarding "sensical" "chalant" and so on.  **Of course** you can humorously, or rarely, "de-prefix" such words as the SWR here.  It would be absurd to think this invalidates the question, or any specific such SWR word.

Comment: i suspect that _apt_ is the non-prefixed form of _inept_.  As for unperturbed/ perturbed, I find nothing "odd-looking"  about _perturbed_ (not that that would disqualify it anyway!) In fact, _perturbed_ is, and always has been, more common than _unperturbed_. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Perturbed%2Cunperturbed&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1650&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CPerturbed%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bperturbed%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPerturbed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cunperturbed%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bunperturbed%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUnperturbed%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Perhaps he meant _imperturbable/perturbable_  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Perturbable%2C+unperturbable%2C+imperturbable&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1650&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cperturbable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cunperturbable%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bunperturbable%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUnperturbable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cimperturbable%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bimperturbable%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BImperturbable%3B%2Cc0

Comment: And then there's _immaculate/maculate_.  "maculate" **as an adjective** is nonexistent in Google Ngram. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=maculate_ADJ_%2Cimmaculate&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimmaculate%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Meelo: I'm just the messenger. I do not necessarily endorse every exemplar put forward by 2wheels. Don

Comment: @JoeBlow: I'm just the messenger. I do not necessarily endorse every exemplar put forward by 2wheels. Don

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: I'm just the messenger. I do not necessarily endorse every exemplar put forward by 2wheels. Don

Comment: @rhetorician: nothing personal intended. Thanks for finding the link.  I went to 2wheels site and tried to post a comment there, but to no avail.

Comment: Thank y'all for your help! As I was searching for more information, I found a page on "back-formations", which suggests many of "rare", nonprefixed version of the word were invented AFTER the prefixed version: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_back-formations